# Flutter app screen blur on emulator

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hi just created HelloWorld flutter application,
all the instructions followed by the official site,
if i run the application on emulator/genymotion getting blur screen, please check the attached image.
if i run same application on device then it is working fine.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some devices are not properly recognized to not support hardware rendering.

Run with the additional parameter

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```

See also

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15451
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15605

Comment: Glad to hear :) It's quite a common issues.

Comment: Is that a solution to shadow problem on emulators too ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet not sure what you mean with "shadow problem on emulators".

Comment: There another similar problem. Where shadows becomes fully opaque and text looks similar to a QRcode

Comment: It's possible, I can't remember seeing this issue mentioned before. Should be easy to test if you can reproduce.